# Gradle error when creating minecraft modding environment

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am constantly getting this error when I try to set up my minecraft modding environment:

```
> No signature of method: org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.whenReady() is applicable for argument types: (SetupUtpTestResultListenerAction) values: [SetupUtpTestResultListenerAction@(some kind of id)]
Possible solutions: whenReady(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

What I'm currently using:

- Windows 10
- IntelliJ Idea community, 2022.1.3
- Forge MDK 1.8.9 Recommended

I am using this [modding tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Hyd8ZtJl1o).

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me.

**How to reproduce my problem:**

You basically want to follow every step in the tutorial like downloading forge MDK etc... until 8:02

There You want to select the build.gradle file in the project folder in IntelliJ. After opening it as a project a little gradle icon should be visible on the right side beside the 3 vertical dots. When you click the icon, gradle files should be visible. You want to open forgegradle and double click the SetupDecomp workspace file. After doing all of this, I get this error

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you. The link to the tutorial is not helpful, we need to know what you actually did, not what you were trying to follow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I believe things have changed slightly since that tutorial, as its for 1.12. You can find the up-to-date steps in the `README.txt` file in the MDK folder that you've downloaded.

Follow the steps from your tutorial up until running `setupDecompWorkspace` in IntelliJ, and simply just run `genIntellijRuns` instead.